# Grails list() - handling Out of memory and restricting list results

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I am facing following problems in Grails.

Here is my code in which I am trying to get list of all possible data and display it.

```
def c = Abc.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(){
  eq("A", "a")
  eq("B", "b")    
}
```

As the results is huge it goes on fetching them and dies.
I want to restrict the list fetch or put max size for it.

I tried using `maxResults()` but it act as a late filter.

I want to put a

1. timeout
2. restrict the fetch
3. if possible, handle all data without hitting Out of memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "late filter", but as far as I know the following in a criteria query

```
maxResults(10)
```

is identical to

```
LIMIT 10
```

in an SQL query. You can verify this by turning on SQL logging. In other words `maxResults(X)` will limit the number of records returned by the query itself.

Comment: Hi Donal, by late filter I meant may be it getting all list of data and then picking max of it which is specified by maxResults(x). I even tried the same way but it ends up with out of memory issue.

Comment: I want to restrict the huge data before it gives an outofmemory or timeout error. Or in any way I can handle these data in list() as shown in example.

Comment: @AmyPrIce as I said in my answer, `maxResults` does not perform what you call a "late filter". It restricts the size of the results that are returned by the query itself

Comment: I understand that, but still not sure why the query is getting timed out when we have to search for huge files even thought I have given maxResults(10) as 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination then

```
params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 10, 100)
def c = Abc.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(params){
    eq("A", "a")
    eq("B", "b")    
}
```

view:

```
<g:paginate controller="myController" action="myAction" total="${results.totalCount}" />
```